# Rasa Core - Understanding Stories

Tags: machine-learning, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am having a difficult time understanding how rasa core interprets stories. Say I have the following:

```
Slot:
 name:
  type: text
 animal:
  type: categorical
  values:
  - dog
  - cat
```

How do I write my stories to handle the sad path for a categorical slot?

```
*greet
 - utter_greet
 - utter_please_give_name
*inform{"Name":"Name"}
 - utter_hello
 - utter_ask_animal
*inform{"Animal": "Dog"}
 - utter_hello_fido
 - action_restart

*greet
 - utter_greet
 - utter_please_give_name
*inform{"Name":"Name"}
 - utter_hello
 - utter_ask_animal
*inform{"Animal": "Cat"}
 - utter_hello_kitty
 - action_restart

*greet
 - utter_greet
 - utter_please_give_name
*inform{"Name": null}
  -utter_please_give_name

*greet 
 - utter_greet
 - utter_please_give_name
*inform{"Name": "Name"}
  -utter_ask_animal
*inform{"Animal": **"?????"**}
 - utter_please_tell_animal
```

Also if I give a partial story in stories.md, like below, how does rasa connect the graph on the back to know what to do next? Does it read each story as an independent flow?

```
*greet
 - utter_greet
 - utter_please_give_name
*inform{"Name": null}
  -utter_please_give_name
```

Thank you, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the sad path simply omit the slot annotation, e.g.:

```
## sad path
*greet
 - utter_greet
 - utter_please_give_name
*inform
  -utter_please_give_name
```

Depending whether you use [augmentation](https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/#data-augmentation) the single stories are glued together during the training to provide more training data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle all animals names so simply you can add more categories or make a custom action to fetch some api to call an animal name or something,  Rasa is learning by examples anything not entered in data or domain will act as strange text.